# TailwindCSS styles not applying and causes error with Angular 7

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, npm, tailwind-css

Basically, applying classes onto my HTML doesn't apply any styling. I've followed the exact instructions on here https://tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/angular using angular-cli@16 and it's worked fine, but when I repeat the steps on angular-cli@7 (what my workplace uses), I get this error here

```
ERROR in ./src/styles.less (./node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/angular-cli-files/plugins/raw-css-loader.js!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??embedded!./node_modules/less-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--15-3!./src/styles.less)
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/less-loader/dist/cjs.js):


@import 'tailwindcss/components';
@import 'tailwindcss/utilities';
```

Not sure if it's a compatibility issue with the version of Angular that we're using (Angular 7), since the steps make Tailwind work fine with Angular 16. I've also tried swapping

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

for

```
@import 'tailwindcss/base';
@import 'tailwindcss/components';
@import 'tailwindcss/utilities';
```

but that has failed to do anything as well. Also, we're using Less as a preprocessor, not sure if that affects anything. Would really appreciate help as I've been trying to figure out how to fix this for hours now.